# .Include versus .Select in entity framework for eager loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

what are the differencies between specifying the folloiwng:-

```
viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors
.Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))
```

AND

```
viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors
.Include(i => i.Courses.Department))
```

will the second query have the same effect (on regards to the eager loading for the navigation property) by retriving both the Courses and the Department navigation properties for the intended Instructor object without using the .Select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Courses` is a collection, the first approach is the right one. The second one would only be applicable if `Courses` was a *single* reference to another entity.

Comment: thanks for the reply, although this is not the case in question, but if we assume that Courses is a single reference so will ".Include(i => i.Courses.Department))" provides eager loading for both; the single entity Courses and its Department collection ? BR